# How to increase the Font Size of a PDF Field in ItextSharp(PdfStamper)?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pdf, itext

I am using PdfStamper to create PDF at run time. My problem is that I am not able to increase the font size of a PDF field. I have tried this but no luck,

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty("names", "textsize", 4f, null);
Font font = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 2f, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD);    
stamper.AcroFields.AddSubstitutionFont(font.BaseFont);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can find some help in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275438/using-different-fonts-in-pdf-using-itextsharp-and-pdfstamper) witch contains a simular problem.

Comment: @user960567 can you please add the solution for it or accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it working using

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty("names", "textsize", 4f, null);
```

but it has to be set before the field is filled

Comment: The critical part for me was the IT HAS TO BE SET BEFORE the field is filled.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Which version of iTextSharp are you using? I have 5.0.6.0 and the following line of code works for me:

```
stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty("SomeDateField", "textsize", 8f, null);
```

However, I encountered an oddity... the above line **only** works for me if that field's font size is set to `Auto`.  When it is set to a fixed font-size, I can't seem to change it through code (I tried several different ways that I had come across).

I'd be curious if you experience the same if you set that field to Auto font-size in Acrobat.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've been able to ascertain, it looks like the font size is completely relative to the horizontal and vertical width of the text field.  I have played around with a few processes to try to "re-size" the text at run-time, but none have yielded any results.  The only "false-positive" I was able to produce was when I re-sized the text field manually.  Sorry this wasn't more helpful to solving your problem, I just figured I would share my experience with this same problem.  I'll keep an eye out for any solutions though, and if you manage to come up with a solution for this, please post it, because it would be very valuable knowledge.

Comment: I was able to solve this by creating multiple pdf forms which different font.

Answer (score 0):

To change font size for every form field you could do it like this:

```
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileInfo.FullName))
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms))
        {
            SetAcroFields(pdfStamper, myModel);

            // flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
            // to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            foreach (var f in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
            {
                //Change font size here if auto should not be used
                pdfFormFields.SetFieldProperty(f.Key.ToString(), "textsize", (float)8.0, null);
            }
        }
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```